# crud operation in typescript: Cannot find name customer in typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, crud

I am creating a crud using typescript,
I just started **typescript** and don't know anything about typescript.

i am creating crud with the help of [this example](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/using-typescript-to-perform-crud-operations.htm)

here my api part is ready and when i started with typescript,

i am getting error on this line

[image]

**error**:[image]

my whole code block

```
/// <reference path="typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
module StudentModule {
    export class Student {
        Id: number;
        Fname: string;
        Lname: string;
        Address: string;
    }
    customer(callback: any) {
        $.getJSON("api/customers", callback);
    }
}
```

what is wrong here,

and, can anybody suggest me better example for crud operations?

Comment: Seems good to me, any hint from your editor ?

Comment: @Striped edited my question

Comment: I'm not familiar with TypeScript but I think your method `customer` should be within your exported class, not outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If customer be apart of the Student class, your code should be:

```
/// <reference path="typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
module StudentModule {
    export class Student {
        Id: number;
        Fname: string;
        Lname: string;
        Address: string;

        customer(callback: any) {
            $.getJSON("api/customers", callback);
        }
    }
}
```